# How to make a layout to fill the space until another layout at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Ilutration:

**"----"** indicates a Layout area

**"...."** indicates another Layout area

```
<-------------------->
<----<TextView_1>---->
<-------------------->
<-<..<TextView_a...>-> 
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...         >...>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<..*layout_end*..>->
<-------------------->
<----<TextView_2----->
<-----         >----->
<-------------------->
```

The content of the **"...."** layout is just **TextView_a**, that isn't big enough to fill until the ***layout_end***.

If I put **match_parent** in the **"...."** layout, the **TextView_2** doesn't appear. Like this:

```
<-------------------->
<----<TextView_1>---->
<-------------------->
<-<..<TextView_a...>-> 
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...        />...>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<..*layout_end*..>->
```

I need to **"...."** layout fills the space, but leave a space just for the **TextView_2**.
What can I do to have the hight result? That result:

```
<-------------------->
<----<TextView_1>---->
<-------------------->
<-<..<TextView_a...>-> 
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...          ...>->
<-<...         >...>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<................>->
<-<..*layout_end*..>->
<-------------------->
<----<TextView_2----->
<-----         >----->
<-------------------->
```

Right: http://s30.postimg.org/f63iski0h/correto.png
Wrong: http://s11.postimg.org/jdq8al71f/incorreto.png

Comment: could you link some images, instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a vertical linear layoutlike this:

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="mtch_parent"> 

     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="48dip"/>        

     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1">

         <!-- put your TextView here -->
     </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="48dip"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace buttons with whatever you want. Even layouts.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/topbutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottombutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/middlebutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottombutton"
    android:layout_below="@id/topbutton" >

</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting another layout, then put TextView2 inside that layout. Then when you applyed match_parent attribute to layout 1's height, it will fit until layout2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and suggest that you want an activity where the first TextView is a header, the second contains the body, and the third is the footer. In this case, wrap_content and match_parent are your friends.

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding_top="15dp"
    android:padding_bottom="15dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding_top="5dp"
    android:padding_bottom="5dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding_top="15dp"
    android:padding_bottom="15dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Heights for top and bottom are adjusted by padding, while the middle one fills in the rest of the space.